# flutter - dismiss alertdialog with code condition

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function to open an `alertDialog` to prevent user from touching or changing while the app is getting data from server:

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigationKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

Future _processing(String s) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: _navigationKey.currentState.overlay.context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            content: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    s,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ));
      },
    ).then((val) {
      print('processing dialog close');
      // _mainBloc.add(SwipeProfile());
    });
  }
```

I need a way to close this dialog after all the data is downloaded, not using click or button to close it. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `Navigator.of(context).pop();` does the trick

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you trigger the fetch data function

Simple example - imperative :

```
_processing() async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // replace "Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5))" with your API call
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((_) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        });

        return AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          content: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Hi",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's your question is how to know when should you dismiss it. When you start request to `_mainBloc`, you should also listen from the stream inside of `_mainBloc`. Check the response data and you can use any of the following to dismiss your dialog:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
Navigator.pop(context);
```

You can also use that to return the result of the dialog (if it presented the user with choices)